# Passing value from codebehind to js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, arrays

I have this javascript code that does show objects on the map:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript">
            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

            function init() {
                var locations = [
                    [40.6128, -73.9976, "images/pin-apartment.png", "estate-details-right-sidebar.html", "images/infobox-offer1.jpg", "Fort Collins, Colorado 80523, USA", "$320 000"],[41.6926, -87.6021, "images/pin-house.png", "estate-details-right-sidebar.html", "images/infobox-offer5.jpg", "E. Elwood St. Phoenix, AZ 85034, USA", "$300 000"]
                ];

                offersMapInit("offers-map", locations);
            }

        </script>
```

But I want it to be populated from the database/c#. How can I do that?

How can i pass that kind of array from the my page_load to this js script?

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: You need to perform a Http request from js to C#. It seems like you're working with WebForms, in that you need to create a Web Service. Check this guide: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14610/Calling-Web-Services-from-HTML-Pages-using-JavaScr

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize a C# array using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`. e.g.

```
protected string StringArray { get; set;}
Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   StringArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new string[] {"foo", "bar"});
}
```

In Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    function init() {
        var locations = <%= StringArray %>;

        offersMapInit("offers-map", locations);
    }

</script>
```

You can also declare the variable from C#:

```
var stringArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new string[] {"foo", "bar"});
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "locations", $"var locations = {stringArray};", true);
```